# .net & access database connection issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ms-access

I have just started using Visual Studio 2013 for web to create a website using blank forms and I am struggling with (what I think) is an Access database connection. I have created forms that can pull and update data in the database but when I have tried to create a registration form using text box's to insert data but I am getting the below error message. I know this code isn't great I have just started to learn this! Please can anyone help me?

Error message:

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'provider'. at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable
>   parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable
>   synonyms, Boolean firstKey) at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString,
>   Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String
>   connectionString) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String
>   connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions&
>   userConnectionOptions) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString,
>   SqlCredential credential) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString) at
>   Registration.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\lou\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\WebSites\BeautyExperts\Registration.aspx.cs:line 22

Registion.aspx.cs code:

```
    `enter code here`using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data.OleDb;

    public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UsersConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();

                string insertQuery = "insert into login (first_name,last_name) values (@first_name,@last_name)";

                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", TextBoxFirstName.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", TextBoxLastName.Text);


                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Redirect("UsersGridView.aspx");
                Response.Write("Registration successful");
                conn.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString());
            }
    }
}
```

Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LoginConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\lou\Documents\BeautyExpertsDB.accdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
    <add name="UsersConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\lou\Documents\BeautyExpertsDB.accdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
    <add name="Users1ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BeautyExpertsDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the connection string I can't see is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean the connection string "UsersConnectionString" ? This works fine when with the other forms for updating and viewing items within the database?

Comment: share UsersConnectionString value , which is in web.config

Comment: Thank you, config file added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `SqlConnection` to access `Ole` hence the error. Change your C# code to use `OleDbConnection` and related commands i.e `OleDbCommand` and it should work just as expected.

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Your Connection String"))
{
   //Do something here 
}
```

Further reading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I have been really stuck on this and it's so simple! I had already tried the OleDbConnection but when I was researching an answer I didn't come across anything about the OleDbCommand.